# + symbol not coming in php GET variable read from url

Tags: php

I am retrieving a GET variable from URL which contains "+" in between the string.
But PHP is storing "space" instead of "+"

PFB output :

```
in URL : key=7VR47WOtmD+acS0  
php echo : echo rawurlencode$_GET['key']) ;
//returns 
7VR47WOtmD acS0
```

Could you please tell me how to get + symbol in the php output ?

**Note:** do not suggest find and replace option

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to encode reserved characters (`$ & + / : ; ? @` etc) if you want to use them in an URL. You need to use `%2B` instead of `+`. If you're using PHP to generate the URL, then you can use the function [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) to automatically encode all characters that require encoding.

Comment: its a link from email which is containing the variables, i am reading.

Comment: @logan: So, URL-encoding is not an option?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's how URLs work. The character + in URLs must, because of the URL specification, be interpreted as a space, as plain spaces are not allowed in URLs. If you want to send a true + character (or a space for that matter) you must escape it using something like `encodeURIComponent("+")` (in the browser) or `urlencode("+")` in PHP, before sending it.